# Azure deployment fails - JsErrorScriptException

Tags: git, azure, typescript

I am trying to push live latest version of the code,with minor changes. I am using the deployment via git . However,  the code fails to build with an error:

```
VSTSC : Script failed with error : 'JsErrorScriptException (0x30001)'.
VSTSC : error : Debug Failure. False expression: 
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files  (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"                "D:\home\site\repository\Project\Project.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build         /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder     /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d41f83f0516280";AutoParameterizationWebConfigCo    nnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false     /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

This error never appeared before and now it started appearing then I try to redeploy previously working commits.

The project is using .net 4.6, typescript&angular2. The only change which I done is changed the typescript version from 2.0.3 to 2.1.0 . But again, the site won't redeploy anymore from older commits.

Thank you for your help

**Update 1:**

I managed to get more detailed error output in azure's console. It is complaining about :

error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 
And other errors like that.

However, in the project's csproj file I allow *.ts compile only in debug mode,by placing them into one ItemGroup